# Import chainer in python throws error

Tags: python, anaconda, chainer

I get the error:

> module 'matplotlib.colors' has no attribute 'to_rgba',

when i import chainer in ipynb.
I am using python 2 ,anaconda 4.1.1 ,chainer 4 and matplotlib 1.5.1.could anyone asses the problem

Answer (score 0):

Try restarting your text editor and trying it, sometimes it needs to be restarted for changes to take effect.

Answer (score 0):

The matplotlib.colors.to_rgba  not available in the version matplotlib==1.5.1.
 First update the matplotlib to latest vesrion.
 command to upgrade the matplotlib

```
pip install --upgrade matplotlib
```

and then try this.It should be fine.

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.colors.to_rgba(c, alpha=None)
```

reference links
https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.colors.to_rgba.html
https://matplotlib.org/users/colors.html

Answer (score 0):

You can solve the issue by:

- updating `chainer` to v4.2.0 or later, OR
- updating `matplotlib` to v2.0 or later

See also: https://github.com/chainer/chainer/issues/4670